# How to get rid of parenthesis in numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data as numpy matrix which I print out looks like this:

```
[[(-1.04928127, 2.05988545e-01, 0.20211728)
  (-1.07234305, 2.10654695e-01, 0.20648511)
  (-1.09539074, 2.15330274e-01, 0.21084299) ...
  (-0.0038786 , 1.05857515e-04, 0.00064304)
  ( 0.        , 0.00000000e+00, 0.        )
  ( 0.        , 0.00000000e+00, 0.        )]]
```

I don't know why I have some parenthesis instead of having [[ only, I have [[( )]]. How can I get rid of parenthesis so I can work with my data as numpy matrix? I tried to loop through the data but I can't unpack them and create a new array.

Comment: Can you add details or an example for the creation of such a list? I am not able to reproduce this scenario, so it is difficult for me to help you. Have you tried `np.asarray`? If so did you get an error message?
Are all your tuples the same size?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What shape and dtype is your array? Is it possible that you have a numpy version before 19 and you have a ragged sequence, so it keeps everything as rows of tuples?

Comment: The () aren't just a decoration.  They tell us something about the array's structure.  What is its `shape` and `dtype`?

Comment: shape is : (1, 4820) while it should be 4820*3.
dtype is : {'names':['F1X','F1Y','F1Z'], 'formats':['<f8','<f8','<f8'], 'offsets':[8,16,24], 'itemsize':232}
and  type is: <class 'numpy.matrix'>

Comment: So you have a `structured array`, with a compound `dtype`.  You have 3 fields instead of 3 columns.  The `()` wrap a `record`. You can use `numpy.lib.recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured` as documented near the end of  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html to convert this to an unstructured array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the dtype information provided in the comment, I can recreate your array:

```
In [2]: dt = np.dtype({'names':['F1X','F1Y','F1Z'], 'formats':['<f8','<f8','<f8'], 'offsets':[8
   ...: ,16,24], 'itemsize':232})
   ...: x=np.array([[(-1.04928127, 2.05988545e-01, 0.20211728),
   ...:   (-1.07234305, 2.10654695e-01, 0.20648511),
   ...:   (-1.09539074, 2.15330274e-01, 0.21084299),
   ...:   (-0.0038786 , 1.05857515e-04, 0.00064304),
   ...:   ( 0.        , 0.00000000e+00, 0.        ),
   ...:   ( 0.        , 0.00000000e+00, 0.        )]], dtype=dt)
In [3]: x
Out[3]: 
array([[(-1.04928127, 2.05988545e-01, 0.20211728),
        (-1.07234305, 2.10654695e-01, 0.20648511),
        (-1.09539074, 2.15330274e-01, 0.21084299),
        (-0.0038786 , 1.05857515e-04, 0.00064304),
        ( 0.        , 0.00000000e+00, 0.        ),
        ( 0.        , 0.00000000e+00, 0.        )]],
      dtype={'names':['F1X','F1Y','F1Z'], 'formats':['<f8','<f8','<f8'], 'offsets':[8,16,24], 'itemsize':232})
In [4]: x.shape
Out[4]: (1, 6)
In [5]: x.dtype
Out[5]: dtype({'names':['F1X','F1Y','F1Z'], 'formats':['<f8','<f8','<f8'], 'offsets':[8,16,24], 'itemsize':232})
```

Recent changes to structured arrays have provided a convenient function to convert such an array to a numeric dtype:

```
In [6]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
In [7]: rf.structured_to_unstructured(x)
Out[7]: 
array([[[-1.04928127e+00,  2.05988545e-01,  2.02117280e-01],
        [-1.07234305e+00,  2.10654695e-01,  2.06485110e-01],
        [-1.09539074e+00,  2.15330274e-01,  2.10842990e-01],
        [-3.87860000e-03,  1.05857515e-04,  6.43040000e-04],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]]])
In [8]: _.shape
Out[8]: (1, 6, 3)
In [9]: __.dtype
Out[9]: dtype('float64')
```

The `str` print of your array gives some clues as to the structured array nature, but they aren't as clear as the `repr` display in [3]:

```
In [10]: print(x)
[[(-1.04928127, 2.05988545e-01, 0.20211728)
  (-1.07234305, 2.10654695e-01, 0.20648511)
  (-1.09539074, 2.15330274e-01, 0.21084299)
  (-0.0038786 , 1.05857515e-04, 0.00064304)
  ( 0.        , 0.00000000e+00, 0.        )
  ( 0.        , 0.00000000e+00, 0.        )]]
```

Records have () and commas internally, but no commas between records (as is normal for elements of arrays).